# Text Adventure Parser C++

Tags: c++, parsing

Me and partner are having trouble with our parser in our Text Adventure game. We keep getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted (core dumped)" errors and we have no idea hot to fix it.

```
 void nextTurn(Player *player)
{
    string input;
    Parser *parser;
    cout << player -> getName() << "'s turn: ";
    cin >> input;
    parser -> parse(input);

    delete parser;
}
```

This is where we get the input from the player in the main class on what each player would like to each turn. Here is our Parser.cpp classe.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Parser.h"
  using namespace std;

  /**
   * Construct a new parser class
   */
  Parser::Parser(Player *p, TownArea *t)
  {
    Parser::player = p;
    Parser::townArea = t;
  }

 /**
 * Parse the input text
 */
  void Parser::parse(string input)
   {
            string action = input.substr(0, input.find(" "));

            //Look around the room
            if(action == "look" || action == "help")
            {
                    cout << "Current Room: " << Parser::townArea -> getName() << endl;
                    cout << Parser::townArea -> getDescription() << endl;
                    return;
            }

            //See player's inventory
            if(action == "inventory" || action == "inv")
            {
                    vector<string> inventory = Parser::player -> getInventory();

                    if(inventory.size() == 0) cout << "Inventory is empty." << endl;
                    else
                    {
                            cout << "Inventory: " << endl << "| ";
                            for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++)
                            {
                                    cout << inventory[i] << " | ";
                            }
                            cout << endl;
                    }
                    return;
            }
 }
```

Comment: Remember to write signatures like `parse(const string& input)` to avoid a lot of copying. Can you step back in your debugger to where it is before it explodes? You probably want to use a `std::map` of commands linked to handler functions, that's a lot easier to wrangle than an endless pile of `if` statements.

Comment: @tadman it stops working at this line  cout << "Current Room: " << Parser::townArea -> getName() << endl;

Answer (score 1):

```
Parser *parser;
cout << player -> getName() << "'s turn: ";
cin >> input;
parser -> parse(input);
```

You merely declared your instance of the `Parser` class. You failed to construct it, with `new`. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Good catch there. This really would be better off with a stack-allocated `Parser` since it's created and deleted in the same block anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate your `Parser`:

```
void nextTurn(Player *player)
{
    string input;
    Parser *parser; // this points to nothing!!!!

    parser = new Parser; // now it points to a Parser

    cout << player -> getName() << "'s turn: ";
    cin >> input;
    parser -> parse(input);

    delete parser;
}
```

However there is no need to use pointers in this case when you simply `delete` it at the end of the function. In this case just use a normal, automatic variable like this:

```
void nextTurn(Player *player)
{
    string input;
    Parser parser; // Don't use a pointer!

    cout << player -> getName() << "'s turn: ";
    cin >> input;
    parser.parse(input);

    // no need to delete here
}
```

Same is likely true of `Player`. Just create a normal instance of it and pass it round by reference:

```
void nextTurn(Player& player) // pass reference
{
    string input;
    Parser parser; // Don't use a pointer!

    cout << player.getName() << "'s turn: ";
    cin >> input;
    parser.parse(input);

    // no need to delete here
}
```

Hope that helps.